# What's the difference between the front brake rotors compared to the rear?

Tags: chevrolet, brake-rotor, silverado

My husband has a 2000 Chevy Silverado 4WD 5.3 he has been trying to find rear brake rotors I'm just curious but what's the difference between the front brake rotors compared to the rear? I'm trying to find these for him as a surprise for our anniversary but don't want to ask him questions, cause then he'll know something is up... If anyone could please help me in anyway, I'd really appreciate it...

Comment: They are different in size and fitment, that are not the same as the front. Try your local auto parts store, they can help you.

Comment: Chevy trucks will have a sticker in the glove box with lots of numbers on them. This sticker describes all the options of the truck. Chevy has a terrible problem with having lots of options for brakes. When you go to the auto parts store bring a picture of that sticker.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

The fitment front and rear are going to be extremely different. Not only is the diameter and braking surface completely different sizes, the rear disks have a separate machined area inside the hat (the part where it attaches to the hub) which is used for the parking brake. The front one has no such provision.

For your husband's 2000 Chevy Silverado, the following are different rear brake rotors by part numbers:

Economy:

- Durago - PN: BR55066
- Bendix - PN: PRT5265
- Centric - PN: 12166041
- Power Stop - PN: AR8641
- ACDelco - PN: 18A952A

Daily Driver:

- Bosch - PN: 25010532
- Centric - PN: 12066041
- Raybestos - PN: 56827
- ACDelco - PN: 18A952

Heavy Duty:

- Bendix - PN: SDR5265
- ACDelco - PN: 18A952SD

You should be able to look these up on Amazon, RockAuto.com, or just Google the part numbers.

I had thought the Silverado/Sierras came with either drum or disks, but I'm not seeing a drum listed for the 2000 model year. My 2006 and my son's 2005 Silverados both have drum rears. Before you order *anything* for your husband's truck, ensure it has disks.

Answer (score 0):

The rotors are similar looking (same number of holes,same shape). The fronts have a single purpose, they get grabbed by the brake caliper and slow the truck. The rears are slightly smaller, as they do less of the braking. The rears actually contain two braking surfaces. The outside has an area for the service brake pads to grab and on the inside contains a braking surface for the parking brake shoe.